# Stata spmap legend key symbol and legend text off not aligned

Tags: stata

I am creating a filled geographical map. I think I have what I want, but for some unexplained reasons, the legend key and the legend text are not in the same line. Would anyone know what is the issue? I have put a blue line at the bottom of the legend to show that the legend text and key symbols are not aligned.
[See here in this map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/injw8.jpg)

Additionally, I found it very odd that I had to start the labelling from "2" instead of "1". What could be the reason for that?

This is the code used to generate the map:

```
spmap predictions using "$shape/district polygons.dta", ///
id(id)  ///
title("TEST predictions") ///
label(data("district predictions.dta")  ///
    xcoord(x_coord) ycoord(y_coord) label(DISTRICT) /// 
    pos(0) size(*0.9))  ///
clmethod(custom)    ///
clbreaks(0 (5000) 30000)    ///
fcolor($colorscale_stata)   ///
legorder(lohi)  ///
legend(pos(11) col(1) rowgap(0.3) size(*1.6) margin(l = 0.6 b = -0.2)   ///
    symysize(*0.9)  alignment(top)  ///
    label(2 "0 to 5000")    ///
    label(3 "5000 to 10000")    ///
    label(4 "10000 to 15000")   ///
    label(5 "15000 to 20000")   ///
    label(6 "20000 to 25000")   ///
    label(7 "25000+")   ///
    title("PREDICTIONS", pos(11) size(4)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly because label 1 is intended for missing data

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31698126)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).